# How to zoom only a particular slice in pie chart (CorePlot ios) and not the entire piechart

Tags: objective-c, core-plot

How to **zoom only** a particular slice in pe chart (CorePlot iOS) and not the entire piechart on user interaction.

I know the following method gives the slice touched:

```
-(void)pieChart:(CPTPieChart *)plot sliceWasSelectedAtRecordIndex:(NSUInteger)index
```

but i want to zoom only that slice ?

Comment: What do you mean by "zoom" a pie slice?

Comment: I mean that the slice which is touched is only zoomed and not all the slices. Furthermore, my intent is to manipulte specific slice , say , change the boundary of a particular slice OR suppose on the touch of a slice the opacity of the **other slices** is reduced.

Is it possible ??

Comment: hai have u got the solution for this? if yes can you please post the code...

Comment: @shalini : I accepted the answer by Eric , sorry dont have code right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can "explode" the selected slice. Implement the `-radialOffsetForPieChart:recordIndex:` method in your datasource and return a positive offset for the selected slice to make it pop out from the rest of the pie.

You can use the `-sliceFillForPieChart:recordIndex:` datasource method to control the fill for each slice. This would allow you to adjust the color and/or transparency to highlight the selected slice.

If you want to make the selected slice larger than the others, use a second pie chart to display the selected slice. Use the same plot data for both plots. On the first one, use the normal slice fill for all but the selected slice, which could be transparent. Reverse that pattern for the second plot, i.e., all slices transparent except the selected one.

Answer (score 0):

You said like below...

If you want to make the selected slice larger than the others, use a second pie chart to display the selected slice. Use the same plot data for both plots.

I need like this concept.I am selecting one slice from outer pie chart and need to load that selected slice value in second pie chart, and make some effects. How to load that value in second chart.Sample code is very handful.

Comment: I don't know how to comment for that top answer, so i wrote this question as answer.
@ Eric Skroch:- Can u post a sample code, it will be more helpful for me.

Comment: What kind of animations are you referring to

Comment: I put a donut chart using core plot, i can select a slice and i changed the radialoffsetvalues and brought the slice outside.Now i need to use that selected slice value to load in another piechart(inner), initially the inner pie chart value will be empty while clicking the outer slice i need to take the value and reload it to inner pie chart.Thx Abi...